# How to remove the table header from a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura, lightning-datatable

I have multiple datatables on my lightning page and I need to remove the Header  element from certain tables.

I cannot use direct styling in CSS because the styling would apply to ALL the tables on the page.

I tried something like this but I wasn't able to reach the thead element as the Locker Services doesn't allow us to traverse through the DOM object (correct me if am wrong or is there a way?):

```
var adjTable = component.find("adjustmentData"); //How to get the thead element here?
$A.util.addClass(adjTable, 'slds-hide'); //Add my class here which might be display:none;
```

**Before**:
[image]
**After**:
[image]

Appreciate any kind of info/articles. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the answer I've linked states, you can't manipulate the internals of a lightning:datatable. You'll have to "roll your own" table if you want to remove the headers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I went for the SLDS Tables approach and now I'm having a hard time getting the <td> values of the table. Tried using both document.getElementById() and component.find(). Please help.

Comment: You should ask a new question with your code so far, we can help you.